# Show that $z^{-1}$ may be written as $r^{-1}e^{-j\theta}$

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

I'm working through an openstax textbook "A First Course in Electrical and Computer Engineering" and stuck on two similar problems relating to multiplicative inverses in [section 3.3](https://cnx.org/contents/fpkWedRh@2.3:BA00y2dK@6/Complex-Numbers-Algebra-of-Complex-Numbers)

**A) Show that $z^{-1}$ may be written as $r^{-1}e^{-j\theta}$**

From my understanding:

$z^{-1} = \frac{x -jy}{x^2 + y^2}$ *(as defined in the text)*

$r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$

$e^{-j\theta} = x - jy$

so:

$r^{-1}e^{-j\theta} = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}) * (x-jy) = \frac{x - jy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \neq \frac{x -jy}{x^2 + y^2}$

**B) Prove $(z^{-1})^* = (z^*)^{-1} = r^{-1}e^{j\theta} = \frac{1}{z^*z}z$**

Just worrying about resolving the $r^{-1}e^{j\theta}$ term here and comparing it to the easier to solve $\frac{1}{z^*z}z$:

$\frac{1}{z^*z}z = \frac{x + jy}{(x-jy)(x+jy)} = \frac{x + jy}{x^2 + y^2}$

$r^{-1}e^{j\theta} = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}})(x + jy) = \frac{x+jy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \neq \frac{x + jy}{x^2 + y^2}$

I'm guessing I must be making a mistake with converting the $r^{-1}e^{j\theta}$ term into cartesian representation, but I've been stuck for a while without seeing the solution.

**Edit:**
It seems my issue is that I was using an incorrect formula for $e^{j\theta} = cos \theta + j sin\theta = x + jy$ which would only be valid if $r=1$

Correctly using the formula
$e^{j\theta} = r cos \theta + j r sin \theta = \frac{x}{r} + j\frac{y}{r} = \frac{x + jy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$ produces the right answers to both questions.

Comment: Why $e^{j\theta}$ is $x+jy$?

Comment: I think you might be taking the long road here.  Note that $z^{-1} = r^{-1} e^{-j\theta}$ is equivalent to $z = r e^{j\theta}$ by taking the reciprocal of both sides.

Comment: The identity $e^{-j\theta}=x-jy$ is not correct. Instead you have $r\cdot e^{-j\theta}=x-jy$.

Comment: @jakobdt Thank you, that sorted it out for me